# Http verb decorator for Django?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, django, django-views, http-verbs

In ASP.NET MVC, you can use the AcceptVerbs attribute to correlate a view function with a verb:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // do get stuff
} 

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    // do post stuff
}
```

[The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter08/) suggests something like this:

```
def method_splitter(request, *args, **kwargs):
    get_view = kwargs.pop('GET', None)
    post_view = kwargs.pop('POST', None)
    if request.method == 'GET' and get_view is not None:
        return get_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    elif request.method == 'POST' and post_view is not None:
        return post_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    raise Http404
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    (r'^somepage/$', views.method_splitter, {'GET': views.some_page_get, 
        'POST': views.some_page_post}),
    # ...
)
```

That seems a little ugly to me - is there a decorator that can associate an HTTP verb with a view, ASP.NET MVC-style, or another accepted way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are standard built-in decorators for requiring particular HTTP method or list of allowed methods.

See the code: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/decorators/http.py.

Comment: This is indeed the way to do it. Note that there's a decorator generator in there as well which lets you create decorators for whatever combinations of methods you like.

(and I have no idea why you got downvoted for giving the obvious and correct answer to the question...)

Comment: I believe this isn't the correct answer, because require_http_methods() is a filter, not dispatcher. One can't do @require_http_methods("GET") for one function, @require_http_methods("POST") for another (with the same name!), and let Django choose the proper one to call by method verb.

Answer (score 9):

**Updated answer in 2016:** Modern Django has everything necessary built-in and available through the [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/class-based-views/). In the most raw form, the canonical approach is subclasssing `django.views.generic.View` and implementing class methods that are named after the HTTP verbs:

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
```

Internally, this works in a way very similar to my ancient code below (which was written before Django had class-based views). There is  a `View.dispatch` method that basically looks up what to call, or return 405 if it can't find anything: `getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)`.

Of course, if you do form processing, template rendering or common CRUD stuff, be sure to check out the available `View` subclasses.

---

**Legacy answer from 2009 below.** The code still works in 2016, but isn't a DRY solution, so don't use it. In 2011 Django got class-based views and nowadays they're the standard way how things should be done. I'm keeping this here solely for historical purposes. Old answer text follows:

In one particular view where I need to have separate code for different HTTP methods (this is my tiny WebDAV implementation), I'm doing something like this:

```
class SomeView(object):
    def method_get(self, request, ...):
        ...

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        m = getattr(self, 'method_%s' % request.method.lower(), None)
        if m is not None:
            return m(request, user, *args, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed("405 Method Not Allowed")

# Then url(r'...', SomeView()),
```

*Added/edited:* Well, I've thought a bit and actually implemented decorator approach. It is not as bad as I initially thought.

```
def method_not_allowed_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponseNotAllowed("405 Method Not Allowed")

def http_method(*methods):
    methods = map(lambda m: m.lower(), methods)
    def __method_wrapper(f):
        this_module = __import__(__name__)
        chain = getattr(this_module, f.__name__, method_not_allowed_view)
        base_view_func = lambda request, *args, **kwargs: \
            f(request, *args, **kwargs) if request.method.lower() in methods \
                                        else chain(request, *args, **kwargs)
        setattr(this_module, f.__name__, base_view_func)
        return base_view_func
    return __method_wrapper

@http_method('get')
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Thank you for GETting.")

@http_method('post', 'put')
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Thank you for POSTing or PUTting.")

# url(r'...', 'app.my_view'),
```

This post is a community wiki, anyway, so feel free to improve if you like the idea! And the revision history also contains some a bit different approaches I tried before writing this...

Comment: Note, that in most form-processing work you probably don't actually want to separate GET and POST methods, because you are probably going to return page, containing form with errors on unsuccessful POST.

Comment: Nice work – was writing a similar solution when I saw your answer. You've though managed to get to a more elegant result ;)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, there's a lot to improve — current code does not even try to preserve attributes (like __doc__ or __name__) and not really error-prone (for example, there's no signature checking at all). I was thinking about using decorator module (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) but I'm too lazy ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Django, so could you elaborate on why you wouldn't separate GET and POST when processing a form? I thought the POST method could just do something like:

form = SomeForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    # save data
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/somelist')
else:
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Would this not preserve the form state, error messages, etc?

Comment: Hmm, all the formatting in my previous comment was killed, sorry! Hope you can still get the point.

Comment: Because you would have to write return render_to_response(...) part twice. Once in a POST and once in a GET view. And you'll probably duplicate decorators, like @login_required. Duplicating code isn't a good thing to do. I believe, most of time, there's no real gain from separating views in such cases.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [View Decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/)

From the docs:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
def my_view(request):
    # I can assume now that only GET or POST requests make it this far
    # ...
    pass
```